# Better solution to access class that owns the method from a method decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Recently, I faced a problem which was similar to this question:

[Accessing the class that owns a decorated method from the decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753537/accessing-the-class-that-owns-a-decorated-method-from-the-decorator)

My rep was not high enough to comment there, so I am starting a new question to address some improvements to the answer to that problem.

This is what I needed:

```
def original_decorator(func):
    # need to access class here
    # for eg, to append the func itself to class variable "a", to register func
    # or say, append func's default arg values to class variable "a"
    return func

class A(object):
    a=[]

    @classmethod
    @original_decorator
    def some_method(self,a=5):
        ''' hello'''
        print "Calling some_method"

    @original_decorator
    def some_method_2(self):
        ''' hello again'''
        print "Calling some_method_2"
```

The solution would need to **work both with class methods and instance methods**, the method returned from the decorator should work and behave just the same way if it was undecorated i.e. **method signature should be preserved**.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754066/2534890) for that question returned a Class from the decorator and the metaclass identified that specific Class, and did the "class-accessing" operations.

The answer did mention itself as a rough solution, but clearly it had a few caveats :

1. Decorator returned a class and it was not callable. Obviously, it can be made callable easily, but the returned value is still a class - it just behaves the same way while calling, but its properties and behaviors would be different. Essentially, it would not work the same way as the undecorated method.
2. It forced the decorator to return a custom-type class and all the "class-accessing" code was put inside the metaclass directly. It is simply not nice, writing the decorator should not enforce touching the metaclass directly.

I have tried to come up with a better solution, documented in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution.**

It uses a **decorator (which would work on "class-accessing" decorators)** and **a metaclass**, which would fulfill all my requirements and address the problems of that answer. Probably the best advantage is that the "class-accessing" decorators can **just** access the class, without even touching the metaclass.

```
# Using metaclass and decorator to allow class access during class creation time
# No method defined within the class should have "_process_meta" as arg
# Potential problems: Using closures, function.func_globals is read-only

from functools import partial
import inspect


class meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, base, clsdict):
        temp_cls = type.__new__(cls, name, base, clsdict)
        methods = inspect.getmembers(temp_cls, inspect.ismethod)
        for (method_name, method_obj) in methods:
            tmp_spec = inspect.getargspec(method_obj)
            if "__process_meta" in tmp_spec.args:
                what_to_do, main_func = tmp_spec.defaults[:-1]
                f = method_obj.im_func
                f.func_code, f.func_defaults, f.func_dict, f.func_doc, f.func_name = main_func.func_code, main_func.func_defaults, main_func.func_dict, main_func.func_doc, main_func.func_name
                mod_func = what_to_do(temp_cls, f)
                f.func_code, f.func_defaults, f.func_dict, f.func_doc, f.func_name = mod_func.func_code, mod_func.func_defaults, mod_func.func_dict, mod_func.func_doc, mod_func.func_name

        return temp_cls


def do_it(what_to_do, main_func=None):
    if main_func is None:
        return partial(do_it, what_to_do)

    def whatever(what_to_do=what_to_do, main_func=main_func, __process_meta=True):
        pass
    return whatever


def original_classmethod_decorator(cls, func):
    # cls => class of the method
    # appends default arg values to class variable "a"

    func_defaults = inspect.getargspec(func).defaults
    cls.a.append(func_defaults)
    func.__doc__ = "This is a class method"
    print "Calling original classmethod decorator"
    return func


def original_method_decorator(cls, func):

    func_defaults = inspect.getargspec(func).defaults
    cls.a.append(func_defaults)
    func.__doc__ = "This is a instance method" # Can change func properties
    print "Calling original method decorator"
    return func


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = meta
    a = []

    @classmethod
    @do_it(original_classmethod_decorator)
    def some_method(cls, x=1):
        ''' hello'''
        print "Calling original class method"

    @do_it(original_method_decorator)
    def some_method_2(self, y=2):
        ''' hello again'''
        print "Calling original method"

# signature preserved
print(inspect.getargspec(A.some_method))
print(inspect.getargspec(A.some_method_2))
```

Open to suggestions on whether this approach has any ceveats.